# How to use time.Parse with string Go?

Tags: go, time

I have func use to get hour .

```
func GetHourFromAPI(lastUpdate string) int   {
    t, err := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, lastUpdate)
    var hourTime = t.Hour()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    return hourTime
}
```

lastUpdate is type string like this : "20190925141100"
I tried parse lastUpdate with type RFC3339 and get hour . But , system return t= 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 . My issue at time.Parse ? what i am missing ?

Answer (score 2):

Your date string isn't compatible with RFC3339 (`"2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00"`) as it has no `-` or `:` or timezone.  You would need to use the format string `"20060102150405"` and do it like this:

https://play.golang.org/p/_aE-7VDuWV-

```
date := "20190925141100"
t, err := time.Parse("20060102150405", date)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("parse error", err.Error())
}
fmt.Println(t)
```